# Cannot get onclick event to work in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, onclick

I realize that this question may have already been answered, but I just cannot get it work. Keep in mind that this works fine outside WordPress.

> I am getting this error when page is loaded up: (index):54 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at (index):54.
>
> And I am getting this error when Privacy policy is clicked: 
>   (index):50 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
>       at togglePopup ((index):50)
>       at HTMLDivElement.onclick ((index):477)

HTML:

```
<div class="popup-backdrop"></div>
 <div class="popup" onclick="togglePopup()">Privacy policy.

<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
    Popup text to show up.
  </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
const backdrop = document.querySelector('.popup-backdrop');

function togglePopup () {
  popup.classList.toggle('show');
  backdrop.classList.toggle('popup-opened');
};

backdrop.addEventListener('click', closePopup);

function closePopup () {
  popup.classList.toggle('show');
  backdrop.classList.toggle('popup-opened');

};
```

I have included JavaScript in WordPress via functions.php file like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js-file', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js');
```

Also other JavaScript I have in there works.

Any help, please?

Comment: Is your js running before the dom renders?

Comment: do you want achieve this on javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like event listener is trying to bind before the relevant DOM object loads. One possible solution to this problem is to add your event listener once all objects are loaded. Try:

```
  document.onload()=function() {
   const popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
   const backdrop = document.querySelector('.popup-backdrop');
   backdrop.addEventListener('click', closePopup);
  };
```

OR with jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 const popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
 const backdrop = document.querySelector('.popup-backdrop');
 backdrop.addEventListener('click', closePopup);
});
```

Comment: Is this valid JS? It throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {. Maybe it is because I am using jQuery too in the same js file like this: jQuery(document).ready(function() {}, my vanilla js is outside of it though..

Comment: jQuery shouldn't conflict with this. Please check the opening and closing sequence of {} in your is file as it seems to me that is an issue.

Comment: Please see if you can spot a mistake here: http://jsfiddle.net/r0mh7cjp/

Comment: Also When I remove window.onload(){
   const popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
   const backdrop = document.querySelector('.popup-backdrop');
   backdrop.addEventListener('click', closePopup);
 } part then my jQuery scripts start working again..

Comment: I just found out that when I load in javascript file via script tag before body then the popup works, so this wp_enque function is not working like it should..Weird since jQuery part of it works

Comment: I am sorry the syntax was wrong. I have updated the code. You can also try the jQuery alternative as I mentioned in the edit.